# Read XML file using PowerShell and select tags based on conditions

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

I have to parse the file below and display a few tags in a report.

```
<CommChannelQueryResponse>
    <CommChannel>
        <ChannelName>C1</ChannelName>
        <AdapterAttribute>
            <Name>Filename</Name>
            <Value>a.txt</Value>
        </AdapterAttribute>
        <AdapterAttribute>
            <Name>Directory</Name>
            <Value>/dir1</Value>
        </AdapterAttribute>    
        <AdapterAttribute>
            <Name>ArchiveDirectory</Name>
            <Value>/archive1</Value>
        </AdapterAttribute>
        ...
    </CommChannel>
    <CommChannel>
    ...
</CommChannelQueryResponse>
```

Based on another post in this forum, I tried the following and it works.

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content commchannels.xml
$XmlDocument.CommChannelQueryResponse.CommChannel |
    Format-Table -Property @{L="Name"; E={$_.ChannelName}},
        @{L="Filename";Expression={$_.AdapterAttribute.Value[0]}}
```

```
Name Filename
---- --------
C1   a.txt
C2   b.txt
```

I am trying to improve on this since this code depends on the "Filename" being the first attribute. How do I change this to display the `AdapterAttribute.Value` which has `AdapterAttribute.Name = "Filename"`?

I tried the following and as you can see it does not display anything for "Filename".

```
$XmlDocument.CommChannelQueryResponse.CommChannel |
    Format-Table -Property @{L="Name";E={$_.ChannelName}},
        @{L="Filename";Expression={
            $_.AdapterAttribute.Value | Where-Object $_.AdapterAttribute.Name = "Filename"
        }}
```

```
Name Filename
---- --------
C1
C2
```

Comment: `$_.AdapterAttribute.Name = "Filename"` -> `$_.AdapterAttribute.Name -eq "Filename"`. `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I tried -eq and it behaves the same as with "="

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots of code.

Comment: `$_.AdapterAttribute.Value | Where-Object $_.AdapterAttribute.Name = "Filename"` -> `$_.AdapterAttribute | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Filename"} | Select-Object -Expand Value`

Comment: That worked, Ansgar. Thank you. Apologies for the screen shots !

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you want to get into Xpath expressions... (case sensitive)

```
(select-xml "/CommChannelQueryResponse/CommChannel/AdapterAttribute" file.xml).node

Name             Value
----             -----
Filename         a.txt
Directory        /dir1
ArchiveDirectory /archive1

(select-xml "/CommChannelQueryResponse/CommChannel/AdapterAttribute[Name/text()='Filename']" file.xml).node

Name     Value
----     -----
Filename a.txt
```